# Creating diagram for an extremely immense tree using Java

Tags: java, swing, file, tree

The problem is simple. I want to create a vertical tree of values, where as you descend down the levels, the amount of values gets exponentially larger. Let's say the 1st level has 1 numerical value, the next has 10, then the next has 100, then the next has 1000, and so on. The first level is connected to the 2nd level with the use of lines, and the 2nd to the 3rd, and so on, much like a game tree. These values are also evenly spaced, so let's say you have a JPanel which is 500x500. At a y of 100, you have 4 values, and so to evenly space them out, you would have a value at 100, one at 200, and so on.

I've tried incorporating drawString, and connecting them with the drawLine method, and placing this so called diagram on a JPanel. That is actually quite simple, and it works if you only have as many as about 50~ values in a singular level. However, when you only have a 1600x900 screen, you can't fit 100 values (on the x axis, which is 1600) without having a big jumbled up mess.

I was thinking there could be 2 possible solutions for this.

One is that the JPanel is not limited to a set resolution (a.k.a the size of your screen) and is scrollable. If it was 10000 x 900 then making this gigantic tree diagram would actually be quite simple, and I could easily fit the 100 values with enough space between them for the values to actually be discernable. However, as far as I know, it's not possible.

The second solution is that I write these values into a file, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Does anyone know, theoretically speaking, what could be the simplest solution for properly displaying a large tree diagram filled with hundreds of values in a single level?

Comment: *If it was 10000 x 900* - when doing custom painting you override the `getPreferredSize()` method to control the size of the panel. When the panel is added to a JScrollPane the scrollbars will appear when needed.

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible to display a scrolling panel?

Comment: I've never tried to create one 10000 x 900 drawing `JPanel`.  However, creating 10 1000 x 900 drawing `JPanels` are possible.  Displaying them would be a challenge as you would have to place drawing `JPanels` in the GUI as you scroll left or right.

Comment: It depends on what the user wants to learn from the tree, but you could hide all but one of the final subtrees, and allow the user to click on a node to make that the one currently being shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

It turns out it's possible to create one 10000 x 900 drawing `JPanel`.  Adjust the `JScrollPane` preferred size to the size you want to display.  The height should be at least 950 pixels to allow room for the horizontal scroll bar.

I created a checkerboard pattern so you can see that the drawing `JPanel` does scroll.

[image: Example]

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LargeDrawingJPanel implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LargeDrawingJPanel());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Large Drawing JPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(drawingPanel);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1400, 950));
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10000, 900));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            Color[] colors = { Color.RED, Color.BLACK };
            int colorIndex = 0;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    g2d.setColor(colors[colorIndex]);
                    colorIndex = (colorIndex == 0) ? 1 : 0;
                    g2d.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
                    y += 100;
                }
                x += 100;
                y = 0;
            }
        }

    }

}
```